# change (highlight? selected? focus?) on a NSTextField cocoa mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Since i really dont know what its called in cocoa it's kind of hard to google.

The thing i want to do is when a view receives a notification lets say `nextInputField:` i want a special NSTextField to be selected as the one active, and the user should be able to type instantly.

How is this done? What method should i call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out NSWindow makeFirstResponder:

Comment: thats for the nswindow, i have a nswindow with a NSViewController inside where i have to make it first responder

Comment: You can get window from your view controller view. In your view controller: `[[[self view] window] makeFirstResponder:<your text field>]`

Comment: Tried the makefirstresponder in my window and it worked, with `[[[self view] window] makeFirstResponder:fname]` in the view i get (null). Do i have to tell my window to look in the view before i tell my view to look on the fname perhaps, will try that

Comment: Ok, is your view visible when you try to set focus to text field? What is the value of fname? If it is an outlet, make sure it is connected in IB.

Comment: thanks, the problem was that i hade the code in my awakefrom nib but it got visible later.